# Google Places Autocomplete suggestions are rendered in the wrong place within Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

We use the Google Places API for autocomplete suggestions. Implementation in Angular was fairly easy, thanks to both existing libraries and several tutorials on how to implement it yourself, if necessary.

Now I tried both using a library (https://github.com/angular-material-extensions/google-maps-autocomplete) and implementing a directive for it myself. Both solutions work fine, but have the same issue, that after using a couple of inputs with an autocomplete connected, at some point the suggestions pop up in the wrong spot. Sometimes just a few pixels, sometimes even out of screen.

[image]

edit: I managed to track the error down to a scroll position problem. The Places autocomplete element is absolutely positioned on the page. If I scroll and use the autocomplete in a modal, it then is wrongly positioned. Setting `position:fixed` on the `.pac-container` sort of helps, but then the error occurs after scrolling the page.

So many issues about this on SO, how come that google never fixed this?!

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you noticed if it is related with the vertical scroll?

Comment: @satchcoder no, it also happens if I do not scroll the page at all

Comment: @satchcoder ok after some more investigation I did figure out that it is related to vertical scroll. any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Got exact same issue, if you figured it out, do you mind to share your solution ?

Comment: I actually went ahead and implemented the popup myself using the Angular Material autocomplete component.